# chrome - webdriver: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver

I run test cases on chrome and somehow the page was not updated and hanged up there for quite long time. In the test report it displays the error: 
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 310.01 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'QAP', ip: '192.168.0.59', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\lance.liu\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir2704_1002}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=41.0.2272.101, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 424feddedffa90b93174e6114bf9e823

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an out of date chrome driver. I would say try the latest version an see if that helps. Get it [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded chrome driver and monitor the resutls.